# How to set the egress priority mappings permanently

Tags: debian, linux-networking, vlan

I have a setup in Debian buster/sid that uses a tagged subinterface (aka vlan) and works correctly. However I need the egress traffic tagged with COS 3.

I can do it manually with ip link and/or vconfig without problem:

```
sudo vconfig set_egress_map vlan24 0i 3
sudo ip link set vlan24 type vlan egres 0:3 1:3 2:3 3:3 4:3 5:3 6:3 7:3
```

My problem is trying to set this changes permanent between reboots. I tried modifying `/etc/network/if-up.d/vlan` script and adding any of those lines, but after reboot the egress priority is reset to empty.

How can I set the changes permanent?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the raw device for vlan24 is eth0, you could do what you want in `/etc/network/interfaces` like this:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto eth0.24
iface eth0.24 inet dhcp
    vlan-raw-device eth0
    up vconfig set_egress_map "$IFACE" 0 3 1 3 2 3 3 3 4 3 5 3 6 3 7 3
```